# 105 errors java android eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Not too sure why im getting the following errors.

I just cant create a simple hello world app no matter what i do, nothing will compile been trying for hours.

Ive posted all the code i have as well.

[image]

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.rikin.myfirstapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.rikin.myfirstapplication.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Comment: Post the code, all we can really do at the moment is agree that you appear to be getting 105 errors.

Comment: Using AndroidL for unique sdk in manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

probably you have a conflict with the support libraries.

if your project has defined the support library **`appcompat_v7`**

[image]

then delete the **`android-supportv4.jar`** library inside your libs folder.

[image]

**Other cause will be the build target, set your build target to 20, delete the errors and try again.**

Comment: deleted it yet the problem exists.

Comment: don´t forget to Delete the messages displayed in "Problems" then clean the project.

Comment: When i clean the project, it just appears again.

Comment: what built target have you defined?

Comment: Its on build automatically.

Comment: Go to Properties -> Android -> Project Build Target